# Hive query nested arrary

Tags: hadoop, hive, etl

I have a field recording the info of a purchasing cart which is as below. The length of array is not fixed.

```
[["SKU_001","Product Name A","Category1",$10.5,1],
["SKU002","Product Name B","Category1",$20,3]]
```

My gola is to denormalize it into a flat row, which may look like this:

```
SKU    | Product Name   | Category  | Unit Price | Product Quantity

SKU001 | Product Name A | Category1 |  $10.5     |   1

SKU002 | Product Name B | Category2 |  $20       |   3
```

Is it possible to achieve the transformation without writing a UDF?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "lateral view explode(...)" syntax to get the sub-arrays as rows, then select out the individual elements of the sub-arrays to get them as columns.

```
select
  cart[0] as SKU,
  cart[1] as product_name,
  cart[2] as category,
  cart[3] as unit_price,
  cart[4] as product_quantity
from my_table lateral view explode(my_nested_array_field) t as cart
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried explode the nested_array field but field with an unknown exception error executing the hive query.
I am not sure if Hive supports nested-array query. I can only succeed the explode execution with non-nested array, like array(1,2,3).
Any more suggestion?

Comment: I think some guys are working on this problem. see this post: 
https://github.com/rcongiu/Hive-JSON-Serde/issues/47